# Concourse S3 resource can't find simple file; 'no versions available'

Tags: amazon-s3, concourse, concourse-s3-resource

I've got a Concourse trigger set to detect when a particular file appears in an S3 bucket. Using this resource: https://github.com/concourse/s3-resource . Configuration is like so:

```
- name: s3-trigger-file
  type: s3
  source:
      bucket: mybucket
      regexp: filename_that_doesnt_change
      access_key_id: {{s3-access-key-id}}
      secret_access_key: {{s3-secret-access-key}}
```

I use it as a trigger like so:

```
jobs:
  - name: job-waiting-for-s3-file-to-appear
    public: true
    plan:
    - get: s3-trigger-file
      trigger: true
```

Seems like an extremely simple configuration. However, when I start the job and put a file in the bucket, I get 'no versions available'.

[image]

Any suggestions on how I might proceed in troubleshooting? Thanks ~~

Comment: You've provided a regex that doesn't match against a version number. If you are using versioned files on s3, use `versioned_file` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concourse is not detecting `s3-trigger-file`. Here are a few potential causes:

- The `access-key-id` and `secret-access-key` you are using do not have access to the file.
- The filename in your `regexp:` is incorrect. Make sure it's an exact match that includes the file extension.
- There is some networking configuration preventing your Concourse from talking to S3. You can ensure this is not the case by `fly hijack`ing into the check container and using the [Amazon CLI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/) to manually pull the file.